# Oracle SQL: Re-use subquery for CASE WHEN without having to repeat subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, code-reuse

I have an Oracle SQL query which includes calculations in its column output. In this simplified example, we're looking for records with dates in a certain range where some field matches a particular thing; and then for those records, take the ID (not unique) and search the table again for records with the same ID, but where some field matches something else and the date is before the date of the main record. Then return the earliest such date. The follow code works exactly as intended:

```
SELECT
    TblA.ID, /* Not a primary key: there may be more than one record with the same ID */
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(TblAAlias.SomeFieldDate)
    FROM
        TableA TblAAlias
    WHERE
        TblAAlias.ID = TblA.ID /* Here is the link reference to the main query */
        TblAAlias.SomeField = 'Another Thing'
        AND TblAAlias.SomeFieldDate <= TblA.SomeFieldDate /* Another link reference */
    ) AS EarliestDateOfAnotherThing
FROM
    TableA TblA
WHERE
    TblA.SomeField = 'Something'
    AND TblA.SomeFieldDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Further to this, however, I want to include another calculated column which returns text output according to what EarliestDateOfAnotherThing actually is. I can do this with a CASE WHEN statement as follows:

```
CASE WHEN
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(TblAAlias.SomeFieldDate)
    FROM
        TableA TblAAlias
    WHERE
        TblAAlias.ID = TblA.ID /* Here is the link reference to the main query */
        TblAAlias.SomeField = 'Another Thing'
        AND TblAAlias.SomeFieldDate <= TblA.SomeFieldDate /* Another link reference */
    ) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2004-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
    THEN 'First period'
    WHEN
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(TblAAlias.SomeFieldDate)
    FROM
        TableA TblAAlias
    WHERE
        TblAAlias.ID = TblA.ID /* Here is the link reference to the main query */
        TblAAlias.SomeField = 'Another Thing'
        AND TblAAlias.SomeFieldDate <= TblA.SomeFieldDate /* Another link reference */
    ) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2009-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
    THEN 'Second period'
    ELSE 'Last period'
END
```

That is all very well. However the problem is that I'm re-running exactly the same subquery - which strikes me as very inefficient. What I'd like to do is run the subquery just once, then take the output and subject it to various cases. Just as if I could use the VBA statement "SELECT CASE" as follows:

```
''''' Note that this is pseudo-VBA not SQL:
Select case (Subquery which returns a date)
    Case Between A and B
        "Output 1"
    Case Between C and D
        "Output 2"
    Case Between E and F
        "Output 3"
End select
' ... etc
```

My investigations suggested that the SQL statement "DECODE" could do the job: however it turns out that DECODE only works with discrete values, and not date ranges. I also found some things about putting the subquery in the FROM section - and then re-using the output in multiple places in SELECT. However that failed because the subquery does not stand up in its own right, but relies upon comparing values to the main query... and those comparisons could not be made until the main query had been executed (therefore making a circular reference, as the FROM section is itself part of the main query).

I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me an easy way to achieve what I want - because so far the only thing that works is manually re-using the subquery code in every place I want it, but as a programmer it pains me to be so inefficient!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers so far. However I think I'm going to have to paste the real, unsimplified code here. I tried to simplify it to just get the concept clear, and to remove potentially identifying information - but the answers so far make it clear that it's more complicated than my basic SQL knowledge will allow. I'm trying to wrap my head around the suggestions people have given, but I can't match up the concepts to my actual code. For example my actual code includes more than one table from which I am selecting in the main query.

I think I'm going to have to bite the bullet and show my (still simplified, but more accurate) actual code in which I have been trying to get the "Subquery in FROM clause" thing to work. Perhaps some kind person will be able to use this to more accurately guide me in how to use the concepts introduced so far in my actual code? Thanks.

```
SELECT
    APPLICANT.ID,
    APPLICANT.FULL_NAME,
    EarliestDate,
    CASE
        WHEN EarliestDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2004-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'First Period'
        WHEN EarliestDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2009-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Second Period'
        WHEN EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Third Period'
    END
FROM
    /* Subquery in FROM - trying to get this to work */
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.REQUESTED_DTE) /* Earliest date of the secondary event */
    FROM
        EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS_Sub
    WHERE
        PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.PER_ID = APPLICANT.ID /* Link the person ID */
        AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.DEL_IND IS NULL /* Not a deleted event */
        AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* List of secondary events */)
        AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.COU_SDV_VALUE = PERSON_EVENTS.COU_SDV_VALUE /* Another link from the subQ to the main query */
        AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.REQUESTED_DTE <= PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE /* subQ event occurred before main query event */
        AND ROWNUM = 1 /* To ensure only one record returned, in case multiple rows match the MIN date */
    ) /* And here - how would I alias the result of this subquery as "EarliestDate", for use above? */,
    /* Then there are other tables from which to select */
    EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS,
    PEOPLE APPLICANT
WHERE
    PERSON_EVENTS.PER_ID=APPLICANT.ID
    AND PERSON_EVENTS.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* List of values - removed ID information */)
    AND PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2014' AND '31-Jan-2014'
```

Comment: I didn't read too close but can't you just put the `case` expression *inside* the subquery? The result of the subquery would be your translated string instead of the date value.

Comment: shawnt00, I want to re-use the subquery result in several places. Whether it returns a date or a translated string, the fact remains that it will still just return one thing in one place... which means that I have to run the subquery in each and every place I want to use it.

Comment: I'm only going off the query above. If you put the `case` expression inside the subquery then you eliminate the duplication in the subquery: `case when min(dt) between A and B then 'x' when min(dt) between C and D then 'y' end)` Perhaps look at "lateral" and "cross apply" for a clean way to get your last attempt above to work.

Comment: Apologies that I haven't read through the entire question in great detail so it's possible I overlooked something. I've gone ahead an added an answer below using `lateral` which I hope is available on your version of Oracle. (Actually `lateral` may just be a synonym for `cross apply` but I'm not 100% sure since Oracle isn't my expertise.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking ***only*** at restructuring the existing query *(rather that logically or functionally different approaches)*.

The simplest approach, to me, for is simply to do this as a nested query...
- The inner query would be your basic query, without the CASE statement
- It would also include your correlated sub-query as an additional ***field***
- The outer query can then embed that field in a CASE statement

```
SELECT
    nested_query.ID,
    nested_query.FULL_NAME,
    nested_query.EarliestDate,
    CASE
        WHEN nested_query.EarliestDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2004-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'First Period'
        WHEN nested_query.EarliestDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2009-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Second Period'
        WHEN nested_query.EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Third Period'
    END   AS CaseStatementResult
FROM
(
    SELECT
        APPLICANT.ID,
        APPLICANT.FULL_NAME,
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.REQUESTED_DTE) /* Earliest date of the secondary event */
        FROM
            EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS_Sub
        WHERE
            PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.PER_ID = APPLICANT.ID /* Link the person ID */
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.DEL_IND IS NULL /* Not a deleted event */
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* List of secondary events */)
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.COU_SDV_VALUE = PERSON_EVENTS.COU_SDV_VALUE /* Another link from the subQ to the main query */
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.REQUESTED_DTE <= PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE /* subQ event occurred before main query event */
            AND ROWNUM = 1 /* To ensure only one record returned, in case multiple rows match the MIN date */
        )
            AS EarliestDate
    FROM
        EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS,
        PEOPLE APPLICANT
    WHERE
        PERSON_EVENTS.PER_ID=APPLICANT.ID
        AND PERSON_EVENTS.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* List of values - removed ID information */)
        AND PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2014' AND '31-Jan-2014'
)   nested_query
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide your attempt with a subquery in the `FROM` clause, which would have been useful, as that is one way that it can be done:

```
SELECT
    TblA.ID,
    ED.MinSomeFieldDate,
    CASE...
FROM
    TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        SQ_A.Id,
        MIN(SQ_A.SomeFieldDate) AS MinSomeFieldDate
    FROM
        TableA SQ_A
    WHERE
        SQ_A.SomeField = 'Another Thing'
    GROUP BY
        SQ_A.Id
) AS ED ON
    ED.Id = A.Id AND
    ED.MinSomeFieldDate <= A.SomeFieldDate  -- We can do this outside of the subquery since it's MIN and <=
WHERE
    A.SomeField = 'Something' AND
    A.SomeFieldDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Thanks Tom H. Unfortunately my novice SQL skills do not allow me to translate this concept to factor it into my actual code, rather than just the simplified example. Could you please take a look at my edited question and see if it would be possible? Thanks.

Comment: First off, don't put all of your tables in the `FROM` clause - find a good tutorial on SQL and study `JOIN` clauses. Next, you'll alias your subquery as if it were just another table - a set of data is a set of data in this respect. Then you can treat that alias as though it were a table with the aggregated data that you need already in it. You'll also need to alias the aggregate function(s) in your subquery so that you have something to refer to them as. Then it's just like they were columns in the "table" that is your subquery. If you're still struggling then you should probably open a new Q

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without correlated sub-queries or sub-query factoring (`WITH .. AS ( ... )`) clauses using an analytic function (and in a single table scan):

```
SELECT ID,
       EarliestDateOfAnotherThing
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         MIN( CASE WHEN SomeField = 'Another Thing' THEN SomeFieldDate END )
           OVER( PARTITION BY ID
                 ORDER BY     SomeFieldDate
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
           AS EarliestDateOfAnotherThing
  FROM  TableA
)
WHERE SomeField = 'Something'
AND   SomeFieldDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
                        AND TO_DATE('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

And you could do the extended case example as:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE
         WHEN DATE '2000-01-01' <= EarliestDateOfAnotherThing
              AND EarliestDateOfAnotherThing < DATE '2005-01-01'
         THEN 'First Period'
         WHEN DATE '2005-01-01' <= EarliestDateOfAnotherThing
              AND EarliestDateOfAnotherThing < DATE '2010-01-01'
         THEN 'Second Period'
         ELSE 'Last Period'
       END AS period
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         MIN( CASE WHEN SomeField = 'Another Thing' THEN SomeFieldDate END )
           OVER( PARTITION BY ID
                 ORDER BY     SomeFieldDate
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
           AS EarliestDateOfAnotherThing
  FROM  TableA
)
WHERE SomeField = 'Something'
AND   SomeFieldDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
                        AND TO_DATE('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Question: when you put your subquery in the FROM clause, are you able to include other tables in that FROM clause alongside it? My example was highly simplified: the real code includes several other tables.

Comment: Almost certainly but without an example it is difficult to state definitively. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle might be smart enough to optimize the two subqueries, but why bother?  I think the query is more clearly written using a CTE:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select q.*,
       (case . . . 
        end) as another_calculated_column
from q;
```

This is the general structure.  You might need to include additional columns in `q` for your logic.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. One thing however: will this CTE work with a subquery such as mine, which is not stand-alone but relies on referencing values from the main query? I seem to remember that I had tried a WITH x AS thing a while ago for another purpose, but it failed because the CTE query could not stand alone. Can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you could just wrap your query in an outer query and use the case statements in the outer query, something like:

```
select id,
       case when earliestdateofanotherthing between a and b then 'Output 1a'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between c and d then 'Output 2a'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between e and f then 'Output 3a'
            else 'default clause output - a' -- null if excluded
       end some_col1,
       case when earliestdateofanotherthing between a and b then 'Output 1b'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between c and d then 'Output 2b'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between e and f then 'Output 3b'
            else 'default clause output - b' -- null if excluded
       end some_col2
from  (select
           tbla.id, /* Not a primary key: there may be more than one record with the same ID */
           (
           select
               min(tblaalias.somefielddate)
           from
               tablea tblaalias
           where
               tblaalias.id = tbla.id /* Here is the link reference to the main query */
               and tblaalias.somefield = 'Another Thing'
               and tblaalias.somefielddate <= tbla.somefielddate /* Another link reference */
           ) as earliestdateofanotherthing
       from
           tablea tbla
       where
           tbla.somefield = 'Something'
           and tbla.somefielddate between to_date('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Alternatively, you could use subquery factoring (aka Common Table Expression(CTE) / WITH clause) to pull the main query into a subquery, and then select from that:

```
with main_qry as (select
                      tbla.id, /* Not a primary key: there may be more than one record with the same ID */
                      (
                      select
                          min(tblaalias.somefielddate)
                      from
                          tablea tblaalias
                      where
                          tblaalias.id = tbla.id /* Here is the link reference to the main query */
                          and tblaalias.somefield = 'Another Thing'
                          and tblaalias.somefielddate <= tbla.somefielddate /* Another link reference */
                      ) as earliestdateofanotherthing
                  from
                      tablea tbla
                  where
                      tbla.somefield = 'Something'
                      and tbla.somefielddate between to_date('2015-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2015-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'))
select id,
       case when earliestdateofanotherthing between a and b then 'Output 1a'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between c and d then 'Output 2a'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between e and f then 'Output 3a'
            else 'default clause output - a' -- null if excluded
       end some_col1,
       case when earliestdateofanotherthing between a and b then 'Output 1b'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between c and d then 'Output 2b'
            when earliestdateofanotherthing between e and f then 'Output 3b'
            else 'default clause output - b' -- null if excluded
       end some_col2
from   main_qry;
```

The advantage to keeping the subquery in the select clause is that you could benefit from subquery caching, assuming there's an appropriate index. It may or may not be as or more performant than @MT0's solution of using the analytic function to do the work of finding the `earliestdateofanotherthing` column; you'd need to test both solutions against your data and table structures to work out which one is best.

(N.B. I suspect that @MT0's solution will be the best one; I've mainly put this answer forward as an example to how to reuse a column without having to calculate it twice.)

---

With regards to the updated query in your question, this would probably do what you're after:

```
with main_qry as (SELECT
                      APPLICANT.ID,
                      APPLICANT.FULL_NAME,
                      case when min(case when person_events.del_ind is null
                                              and evtype_sdv_value in (/* List of secondary events */)
                                              then person_events.REQUESTED_DTE
                                    end) over (partition by person_events.per_id, person_events.cou_sdv_value) <= person_events.requested_dte then
                               min(case when person_events.del_ind is null
                                             and evtype_sdv_value in (/* List of secondary events */)
                                             then person_events.REQUESTED_DTE
                                   end) over (partition by person_events.per_id, person_events.cou_sdv_value)
                      end earliest_date
                  FROM
                      EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS,
                      inner join PEOPLE APPLICANT on (PERSON_EVENTS.PER_ID=APPLICANT.ID)
                  WHERE 
                      PERSON_EVENTS.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* List of values - removed ID information */)
                      AND PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE BETWEEN to_date('01-Jan-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND to_date('31-Jan-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))
select id,
       full_name,
       earliest_date,
       CASE
           WHEN EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Third Period'
           WHEN EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Second Period'
           WHEN EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'First Period'
       END period_type
from   main_qry;
```

Obviously, you'd have to test it!

Please note:

1. I added explicit conversions of the strings in the main_qry's where clause to be dates, using `to_date`; it's not a good idea to rely on implicit date conversions, especially in production code! NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameters can be easily changed, which would result in difficult to identify bugs!
2. I amended your case statement to take account of the cases where your earliestdate field could fall between the cracks (eg. if it had a date of "31/12/2004 13:03:23"). It also makes it easier to read!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution based on your updated query.

Comment: Hmm. I'm trying your solution, but I'm getting an "Invalid Character" error. The engine in which I'm working doesn't specify where the error occurs. And yes, I did remember to replace my commented text with a list of actual values.

EDIT: aha - the invalid character was apparently the ; at the end! My engine (Business Objects) does not like it. However there's now another error: "Table or view does not exist"...

I'm lost...

Comment: I take it you have the tables EVENTS and PEOPLE? Are you running the query from the same schema as the one that owns the objects? If not, try adding the schema name to the table (eg `OWNING_SCHEMA.EVENTS`). Also, make sure the schema you're running as has the appropriate privileges to both tables.

Comment: Yes, I have both tables in the same schema.

However... I have just succeeded in what I wanted to do by combining your CTE format with my existing knowledge! I was totally lost with the "partition by" stuff, and my attempts to use that code caused errors.

What I did was simply take my existing query, then name it as a CTE (main_qry) in the manner you have shown me - then from that, I was able to re-use the date field! Thanks :)

Comment: If you're not familiar with analytic functions ("the partition by"), I highly suggest that you research them - they're extremely useful. They're very similar to aggregate queries ("group by") except, instead of squishing the data down into one-row-per-group, it outputs the results per row in the original row set. "Partition by" is sort of equivalent to "group by". Anyway, I'm glad you got it working, one way or another! *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `lateral` solution. I've re-ordered your tables and used the ANSI join syntax for the inner join. Also I've never actually written a `lateral` or `cross apply` query on Oracle which I note mostly because I might have made a minor syntax error and the documentation I skimmed doesn't make it clear to me if there's a distinction.

While I don't think it would be difficult to convert this to a form that just uses another inner join I do think this is the concept you were searching for in posing the question.

```
SELECT
    APPLICANT.ID,
    APPLICANT.FULL_NAME,
    EarliestDate,
    CASE
        WHEN EarliestDate BETWEEN
            TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2004-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
        THEN 'First Period'
        WHEN EarliestDate BETWEEN
            TO_DATE('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2009-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
        THEN 'Second Period'
        WHEN EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
        THEN 'Third Period'
    END
FROM
    EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS inner join PEOPLE APPLICANT
        on APPLICANT.ID = PERSON_EVENTS.PER_ID
    LATERAL /* or possibly just CROSS APPLY */
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.REQUESTED_DTE) EarliestDate
        FROM
            EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS_Sub
        WHERE
            PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.PER_ID = APPLICANT.ID
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.DEL_IND IS NULL
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (...)
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.COU_SDV_VALUE = PERSON_EVENTS.COU_SDV_VALUE
            AND PERSON_EVENTS_Sub.REQUESTED_DTE <= PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE
    ) /* I don't think you need an alias here? */
WHERE
        PERSON_EVENTS.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (...)
    AND PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2014' AND '31-Jan-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, thank you so much for all your help. I could understand some of it - and other parts made my head spin. I'm an SQL beginner, so I'm sure I will learn these more complex concepts in time. However, what I have now managed to do is solve my problem using a concept suggested to me in the answer, but which still used the easy straightforward code with which I am familiar.

Basically, instead of making the date-output subquery as a CTE, I have made the whole main original query as a CTE (which stands alone, naturally); and then by using that CTE in a further query, I am able to manipulate that date column as I like. As follows:

```
WITH MAIN_QUERY AS
    (
    SELECT
        APPLICANT.ID,
        APPLICANT.FULL_NAME,
        (ltrim(decode(to_char(APPLICANT.DOB_DD)||'/'||to_char(APPLICANT.DOB_MM)||'/'||to_char(APPLICANT.DOB_YYYY),'//',null,lpad(to_char(APPLICANT.DOB_DD),2,'0')||'/'||lpad(to_char(APPLICANT.DOB_MM),2,'0')||'/'||to_char(APPLICANT.DOB_YYYY)),'/')) AS DOB,
        PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE,
        PERSON_EVENTS.COU_SDV_VALUE,
        /* Find the date of EARLIEST secondary event */
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(PERSON_EVENTS3.REQUESTED_DTE)
        FROM
            EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS3
        WHERE
            PERSON_EVENTS3.PER_ID=APPLICANT.ID /* Ensure same person ID as main query */
            AND PERSON_EVENTS3.DEL_IND IS NULL
            AND PERSON_EVENTS3.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* Secondary event values */)
            AND ROWNUM = 1
        ) AS EarliestDate /* Alias this subquery to a column name, for use later on */
    FROM
        EVENTS PERSON_EVENTS,
        PEOPLE APPLICANT
    WHERE
        PERSON_EVENTS.PER_ID(+)=APPLICANT.ID
        AND PERSON_EVENTS.EVTYPE_SDV_VALUE IN (/* Primary event values */)
        AND PERSON_EVENTS.REQUESTED_DTE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
    )
SELECT
    ID,
    FULL_NAME,
    DOB,
    REQUESTED_DTE,
    COU_SDV_VALUE,
    EarliestDate, /* Use the date by alias - this works */
    /* Then the alias can be further used how I like, without having to re-run the subquery :) */
    CASE
        WHEN EarliestDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2000-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2004-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'First period'
        WHEN EarliestDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2009-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Second period'
        WHEN EarliestDate >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN 'Third period'
    END
FROM MAIN_QUERY
```

So - again, thanks everyone. I am posting this solution here as my preferred one (given my level of SQL expertise), but I would not have been able to do it without your help. I hope this thread serves useful to anyone else looking for the ability to re-use a subquery result without having to repeat it.